# Why is the following statement impossible for a sequence $\{p_n\}$?

Tags: real-analysis

> A sequence is said to be convergent if there is a point to which it converges. A convergent sequence cannot converge to two distinct limits. For if $\{p_n\}$ were to converge to both $p$ and $q$ with $p \ne q$, then we could choose spherical neighborhoods about $p$ and $q$ that are disjoint; but, all but a finite number of the $p_n$ would have to be inside each of these neighborhoods, which is impossible.

I'm a little confused by the following statement.

> but, all but a finite number of the $p_n$ would have to be inside each of these neighborhoods, which is impossible.

Is it impossible by definition of a convergent sequence?

Comment: The definition says that $p_n$ converges to $p$ **iff** for any neighbourhood of $p$, at most a finite number of the $p_n$ lie outside the neighbourhood.

Comment: If $p\neq q$ then only a finite number of points lie outside of a neighbourhood $V_p$ of $p$ such that $q\notin V_p$. But then $q$ cannot be a limit point according to the definition given by @copper.hat.

Comment: However, I have a remark here that experts should check. You cannot take disjoint neighbourhoods in every topological space (the well-known separability axioms). So if I am not wrong, sequences cannot have two different **distinguishable** points as limit, that is different than to say that sequences cannot have two different points $p\neq q$ as limit. For example, in $\mathbb R$ with the trivial topology, there is no topological argument to say that $0$ and $\pi$ are different.

Comment: @Dog_69: Generally one needs a T2 space (Hausdorff), but I don't think these topological subtleties are the OP's focus.

Comment: Yes I know. But still.. The OP can omit my remark, there is no problem. But if the OP wants to go far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence converging to distinct $x$ and $y$. Since $x$ and $y$ are distinct, there are $\varepsilon,\delta>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\cap B_\delta(y)=\varnothing$. By definition of convergence, there are $M$ and $N$ such that $|x_m-x|<\varepsilon$ and $|x_n-y|<\delta$ whenever $m>M$ and $n>N$. However, pick an integer $p>\max\{M,N\}$. Then this says that $x_p\in B_\varepsilon(x)\cap B_\delta(y)=\varnothing$, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to converge to two different points by definition of convergence described by @copper.hat on the comment above. You cannot have only finite number of values outside two disjoint neighborhoods

Comment: That is true as we seem to live in $\Bbb{R}$ with the standard topology. However, it might be interesting to point out that this is not true in arbitrary topological spaces, but requires that the space is Hausdorff.

Comment: For the sequence $p_n=3 + (-1)^n2$, you would have a finite number of values(empty set) outside the balls centered at $1$ and $5$, respectively, which means that $p_n$ is not convergent by definition. Do you mean that "you cannot have only a finite number of values outside two disjoint neighborhoods, and still have a convergent sequence"? Hope that I'm not misunderstanding.

Comment: @K.M: There are an infinite number of your $p_n$ outside the neighbourhood $(0,2)$ of $1$, so $p_n$ cannot converge to $1$. To converge to some $p$, it must be the case that for **any** neighbourhood of $p$ that only a finite number of $p_n$ lie outside. The sequence $p_n$ in your comment does not converge to any point. It has subsequences that converge to $1,5$, but the entire sequence does not converge.

Comment: @copper.hat: You're correct in that we can pick the neighborhood  $(0,2)$ of $1$, and see that there are an infinite  number of $p_n $ outside the neighbourhood  $(0,2)$  of $1$, thus contradicting that $p_n $ converges to $1$. But, Francisco made the statement that "you cannot have only a finite number of values outside two disjoint neighborhoods." I interpreted this as false since we can consider $p_n $ and the two neighborhoods $(0,2)$ and $(4,6) $ and see that there are 0(finite) points outside of the aforementioned, disjoint neighborhoods.